# Share file via my android application

Tags: android, file-upload, share

I am making a service Cloud application. The user can upload a file but he has to open my application and launch the file chooser activity. I want to make something like a shortcut, i want to give the user the possibility to **upload a file to the server without opening my application**. When you select a file, application like facebook and drive propose you to upload or share. So i want to know if it is possible to do that with my application.
Thanks.

Comment: Those apps are kept alive running in the background, so not sure what you are asking is possible.

Comment: Thank you Krity. So if we suppose that the app is already running, how can i make the icon of my app appear (in the list with facebook, drive ...) when the user choose a file ?